Conflict in spring security configuration while using spring boot auto-configuration
I'm writing the auth-starter for all my future spring projects, and I faced with some troubles while trying to use my auth-starter in demo application
so here is the part of my security configuration which located in my auth-starter lib:
package my.company.auth

// imports

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties({KeycloakProperties.class})
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration {

    private final KeycloakProperties keycloakProperties;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain simpleSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
            ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter policyEnforcerFilter) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .addFilterAfter(policyEnforcerFilter, BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
   // some other code here
}

here is my dependencies in auth-starter's pom.xml which are related to security part
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>keycloak-policy-enforcer</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>

here is how I'm using it in my demo-applicaiton
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>auth-starter</artifactId>
      <groupId>my.company</groupId>
      <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

both demo-app and auth-starters uses
    <spring.boot.version>3.3.1</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.security.version>6.3.1</spring.security.version>
    <spring.version>6.1.11</spring.version>

so the problem is when I'm configuring auto configuration it doesn't work as excected (all requests are 403 Forbidden).
As I think it leads to some inner security configuration conflict which I can't find and resolve
here is the META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports file content
my.company.auth.OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration

when I'm deleting this file and just applying @ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.company") in my demo app it works fine (all request are secured as expected)
how I'm using it
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.company")
public class DemoApplication { // which uses auth-starter

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Note: when I'm using the META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports I'm seeing the following in my terminal:
2024-08-25T11:04:01.334+03:00 DEBUG 4659 --- [demo-app] [           main] swordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
2024-08-25T11:04:01.432+03:00 DEBUG 4659 --- [demo-app] [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with filters: DisableEncodeUrlFilter, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter, SecurityContextHolderFilter, HeaderWriterFilter, CorsFilter, CsrfFilter, LogoutFilter, BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter, RequestCacheAwareFilter, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter, AuthorizationFilter
2024-08-25T11:04:01.474+03:00 DEBUG 4659 --- [demo-app] [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with filters: DisableEncodeUrlFilter, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter, SecurityContextHolderFilter, HeaderWriterFilter, LogoutFilter, BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter, ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter, RequestCacheAwareFilter, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter, ExceptionTranslationFilter, AuthorizationFilter
2024-08-25T11:04:01.830+03:00  INFO 4659 --- [demo-app] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'

here is two DEBUG logs with two different security filter chains. So to resolve this I have tried to put @AutoConfigureBefore(org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration.class) but this only solves the problem of the two log presence in the terminal but not the main problem.
Note: In both cases It calls my securityFilterChain method
Note: PolicyEnforcer also works fine in both cases

Policy enforcement on authorization server is inefficient (requires a call roundtrip to the authorization server for each request on each resource server, which could even become a bottle-neck), and introduces tight coupling between the authorization server and resources: rules like can edit a post if "is moderator of the topic" or "is author of the post" would require the authorization server to know what a topic, a post, and an author are, and how it relates to each other. This responsibility assignment issue will become evident when you try to write unit tests access control rules.

Also, you could be interested in this starter I already wrote. It quite complete already.
